# Pango error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-center, python, 14.04, fonts, pango

I can't get `software-center` and other Python applications to run in Ubuntu 14.04.

The error I get in the terminal is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 25, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 68, in load_module
    dynamic_module._load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 294, in _load
    self._introspection_module = get_introspection_module(self._namespace)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 273, in get_introspection_module
    module = IntrospectionModule(namespace, version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 122, in __init__
    repository.require(namespace, version)
gi.RepositoryError: Typelib file for namespace 'Pango', version '1.0' not found
```

I get this for a number of other applications. I tried installing Pango from source, but that didn't help and then I tried installing the `pango-graphite` package which screwed up fonts everywhere.

Does anyone know what is going on and how to revert to the base settings?

Answer (score 1):

So Ubuntu has `pango` in the `gir1.2-pango-1.0` package. Reinstalling that package fixed the problem.